# Selecting custom checkboxes in object sync configuration in Marketing Cloud connector

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

I am using Marketing Cloud Connect to sync objects from my Service Cloud instance to Marketing Cloud. I would like to filter the records that are synced by a formula field (labelled `MarketingCloudUser__c` that is visible in the Contact object (verified it is also visible to the connect cloud users profile).

When I navigate to syncronised sources in Contact Builder it does not show me the field, can anyone explain why?
[image]

Comment: can you please check on the permission for the field level security if you have provided access in Salesforce to the marketing cloud user? Also please confirm that your formula field type is Boolean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Naveen and @Deployment Failure

I was inspired by the above question and tried to implement the same and I was able to achieve the above!

I hope as mentioned by Naveen either you have **missed to add permission**.

OR
As this is a new field created we have to **add this field to sync** as below.

Steps I followed.

#### 1) Created the Custom field `MarketingCloudUser__c`

[image]

#### 2) Created and assigned permission set.

[image]

#### 3) Added the `MarketingCloudUser__c` to sync objects

[image]

#### 4) Now we can chose this field under dropdown! HURRAY!

[image]

Thanks Naveen VM

Comment: you are welcome @Vishal

Comment: Thanks @Vishal, so the program was that the field was not initially sync'ed in your step 3. Syncing the field resolved this.

Comment: Yes @DeploymentFailure